# React. Обновить значение внутри setInterval по внешней переменной

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

Задачка поначалу показалась весьма простой, но когда начал работать с таймером - что-то пошло не так. К примеру:

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState(4);

useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(out, 1500);
}, []);

const out = () => {
    console.log(number);
};
```

В общем нужно, чтобы при смене **number** в консоль выводилось новое значение, а то у меня постоянно выводится **4**. Пробовал делать **clearInterval** и создавать новый таймер при изменении того же **number**, но, в итоге, у меня существовало 2 таймера. Подскажите как оптимально решить задачку.

Comment: А где вы setNumber вызываете?

Comment: Я его выставил в useEffect, как в коде выше. Иначе при перерендере компонента будет появляться по таймеру...

Comment: Показывайте весь код. Пока совершенно непонятно что у вас происходит и что нужно получить

Comment: Но это и есть весь код. Можно добавить input с кнопкой, клик по которой будет обновлять значение в стейте. Вот и всё. А задача следующая: вбить в поле цифру 5, нажать на кнопку (в скейте теперь 5, а не 4) и выводить в консоль 5. У меня выводится всё та же четвёрка, т.е. таймер не получает внешне значение, он как помнил 4, так до такого его и выводит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно например так:

```
import React from "react";

const Timer = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(1);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // таймер пересоздаётся каждый раз когда обновляется number
    const id = setInterval(() => setNumber(number + 1), 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, [number]);

  return <div>Number is {number}</div>;
};

export default Timer;
```

Но даже проще можно написать так:

```
import React from "react";

const Timer = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(1);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setNumber(number + 1), 1000);
  }, [number]);

  return <div>Number is {number}</div>;
};

export default Timer;
```

Потому что в первом варианте из-за особенностей реакта каждый раз пересоздаётся таймер. С одним таймером не будет ре-рендерится обновлённое значение (если оно должно быть не только в консоли):

```
import React from "react";

const Timer = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(1);

  let n = 0;
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // таймер создаётся 1 раз
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(n++);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>Number is {number}</div>
      <div>n is {n}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Timer;
```

Последний вариант - это не Реакт стиль -> bad practice

Comment: Благодарю! Первый вариант мне подошёл. Так как я не раскрывал свою задачу полностью, то второй вариант создал у меня 2 таймера. Третью не тестировал, остановился на первой. Хорошо, что написали несколько решений, наверняка кому-нибудь они пригодятся. Хотя, честно скажу, я не догоняю как работает возврат функции остановки таймера, но именно этот вариант мне помог. Другие варианты остановки таймера мне не помогали.